# How does Any, Optional and Protocol work together in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Can somebody explain why the first snippet is failing and the second is working?

1. Error is optional type

   ```
   var error:Error? = NSError(domain: "MyDomain", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
   var anyError:Any = error
   if let err = anyError as? Error
   {
       print("success")
   }
   else {
       print("failure") // prints failure
   }
   ```
2. NSError is optional type

   ```
   var error:NSError? = NSError(domain: "MyDomain", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
   var anyError:Any = error
   if let err = anyError as? NSError
   {
       print("success") // prints success
   }
   else {
       print("failure")
   }
   ```

Comment: It looks like unwrapping `Any` to a bridged type does not work. This is not pretty, but it gets the job done: `if let err : Error = anyError as? NSError`

Comment: With `var anyError: Any? = error`, then both patterns succeed.

Comment: Note that this is one of many, many little edge cases where `Any` interacts in surprising ways with `Optional` (since every type can be promoted to an optional of that type, and any Optional conforms to Any, so promotions can happen in really surprising ways, and `??` types become common). It is incredibly rare that you should have variables of type `Any`. While it's interesting to explore why this corner case occurs (it might be a compiler bug, it just might be yet any `Any` surprise), if you actually require this code, you have a significant type problem that needs to be addressed instead.

Comment: @RobNapier In the real code, I am passing the Error type which I received from url session delegate through a notification's userInfo dictionary which is of type [AnyHashable : Any]. I could cast it to NSError, but I was just curious as to why this happens.

Comment: There are "reasons," but there's no real "why." The compiler is able to make an `Any` -> `NSError?` -> `let ... as NSError` conversion. It's not able to make an `Any` -> `NSError?` -> `Error?` -> `let ... as Error` conversion; it's one conversion too many. This isn't shocking, since protocols are not covariant (`[Int]` is not `Equatable` for instance), but it wouldn't be shocking if the compiler special-cased out this conversion. So the whole answer is "because the compiler can't get there from here; it's too far. In the other case, it can get the other because it's a step closer."

Comment: You don't have to cast as `NSError`. Just don't use an optional. If this code were `var error:Error = NSError(domain: "MyDomain", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)` then it works fine with `anyError as? Error`. It's just because you've mixed `Any` with Optionals.

Comment: The problem here is I am receiving Error type as an optional from URL session delegate and then I put it in a userInfo dictionary[AnyHashable : Any] and post a notification. The observer of this notification unwraps the error object to check for any error.  In this case it fails. Anyways thanks for the explanation :)